# How does R forecast package treat missing values in ARIMA (auto.arima function)

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, forecast

I run an ARIMA model in R on the data with missing values. It is financial data, so the missings are either days on public holiday or weekends, so not completely at random. I am still thinking which decision I should make on missing values.

However, what I see is that the function itself runs without error. So ARIMA automatically does it treat missing values somehow. But I can't find in documentations what exactly happens with missing values when running ARIMA (just to know whether it drops them/imputes or smth else?)

```
best_fit = auto.arima(data_vector, stationary = is_stationary, ic = "bic", stepwise = FALSE, allowmean = TRUE, allowdrift = TRUE, approximation = FALSE)
```

Does somebody know what auto.arima does by default?

Comment: Does this answer your question:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346225/fitting-arima-to-time-series-with-missing-values

Comment: @MGP so basically in auto.arime  Kalman filter is used,"which is used to fit state space models, deals with missing values exactly by simply skipping the update phase". I am just a bit worried about this, because I cant find absolutely anything in documentation that this is a mechanism of dealing with NAs in this package. Can I somehow check it is what happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`forecast::auto.arima()` uses `stats::arima()` to fit the models. This uses a state space approach to ARIMA models, and computes the likelihood using the Kalman Filter. See the help file for `stats::arima()` which contains an explanation, with several references. In particular, [Jones (1980)](https://doi.org/10.2307/1268324) explains how the missing values are handled in a Kalman Filter. So it does not drop them, or impute them. It simply computes the likelihood based on the available data by skipping the updating part of the Kalman Filter.

Comment: can I ask another follow up? How does this ARIMA function treat the fact that I have many NAs just before the forecast start dates. I basically have several versions of the variables (financial data, so different maturity). And same forecast date. But the one series which has many NAs just before forecast date (it does not have that many before, but around this date) shifts a bit forecast on graph. Can it be because of the package or I don't understand smth about ARIMA? For other years without NAs before forecast start date, forecast starts right after, so all good.

Comment: NAs before the forecast origin mean the first forecast is actually a multi-step forecast based on the non-missing data.

Comment: last question sorry. Now I ran ARIMA with auto_arima function both on data with missing values and on the same one if I drop the missings myself, I get same coefficients, but different standard errors. Would not I expect my coefficients to be different if auto arima uses Kalman Filter for updating

Comment: I think that will depend on the specific model being fitted. For some models, the one-step forecasts will be the same as the multi-step forecasts, and so the likelihood is unchanged without the missing values.